# Find an address of injected code via GetModuleHandleA

Tags: ida, ollydbg, x64dbg, dll-injection, injection

I am reversing really old game (20 years old).

l2.exe loads Dsetup.dll Network.dll. (not sure about order)

inside of the Dsetup.dll i found and injection (kind of protection) into module Network.dll. That changes 1 network packet.

The injection:
[image]

A list of loaded modules:
[image]

**The question is how to find a place where this injection was done. Base address of initial Network.dll + offset like 177126 ? As a result i have not valid address**